# pop up warning message when scraping

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, web-scraping

I am using selenium to scrape this website: 
https://www.fedsdatacenter.com/federal-pay-rates/index.php?y=all&n=&l=&a=&o=

My codes work well by keeping clicking next and parsing the table until a warning message comes out:

> DataTables warning: table id=table-example - Invalid JSON response.

and my code stops because of this error. Even manually, clicking next gives me the same warning.

Here is my code. What can I do about it? And if there is any way to improve my code, help me please.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time


def has_class_onclick(tag):

    return tag.has_attr('onclick')


def extract_table_content_into_rows(website_lists):

    # This function is to extract all the table content from and put them into a list of row.

    list_of_row = []

    for table_page in website_lists:
        soup_page = BeautifulSoup(table_page, "html.parser")
        soup_table_raw = soup_page.find("table")
        if soup_table_raw:
            soup_table = soup_table_raw.find("tbody")
            for soup_row in soup_table.find_all("tr"):
                row_content = []
                for soup_column in soup_row.find_all("td"):
                    if not soup_column.contents:
                        row_content.append(".")
                    else:
                        column_content = soup_column.contents[0].strip()
                        row_content.append(column_content)
                list_of_row.append(row_content)
        else:
            continue

    return list_of_row


def csv_writer(lists_of_row):

    # This function is to write the table contents into a csv file.

    with open("federal.csv", "at", newline="") as csvfile:
        for row_to_write in lists_of_row:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerow(row_to_write)


driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('https://www.fedsdatacenter.com/federal-pay-rates/index.php?y=all&n=&l=&a=&o=')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table-example_length"]/label/select').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table-example_length"]/label/select/option[4]').click()
time.sleep(3)


page_num = 1

while page_num > 0 and page_num <= 5:
    html = driver.page_source
    website_list = [html]
    row_list = extract_table_content_into_rows(website_list)
    print(row_list)
    csv_writer(row_list)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table-example_next"]/a').click()
    time.sleep(3)
    print(page_num)
    page_num += 1

while page_num > 5:
    html = driver.page_source
    website_list = [html]
    row_list = extract_table_content_into_rows(website_list)
    print(row_list)
    csv_writer(row_list)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table-example_next"]/a').click()
    not_find = 1
    while not_find == 1:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table-example_paginate"]/ul/li[6]/a')
            while driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table-example_pagina'
                                               'te"]/ul/li[6]/a').text != str(page_num + 2):
                time.sleep(0.1)
            not_find = 0
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            continue
    print(page_num)
    page_num += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to disable all alerts on the page by using some JavaScript:

```
driver.execute_script('window.alert = function() {};')
```

Comment: But when I manually click the next button, it pops up the same warning message...It seems that I simply cannot move onto the next page at that time.

Comment: @yuhengwang Yes, if you can't do it manually then you can do it using the webdriver. The above just suppresses the warning, not let you do operations that you are not supposed to do.